# How to refresh currently active page in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a global function that I call from almost all screens of my app. I am passing context to it. I just want to know if there is a way to refresh the page from which the global function is called depending on context passed to the function?

```
appResumedPausedLogic(context,[bool isVisitPage]){
  SystemChannels.lifecycle.setMessageHandler((msg)async{
if(msg=='AppLifecycleState.resumed' )
{
  print("------------------------------------ App Resumed-----------------------------");

  var serverConnected= await checkConnectionToServer();
  if(globals.globalCameraOpenedStatus==false)
    if(serverConnected!=1){

      Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => OfflineHomePage()));

    }
    else{
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
    }



}
if(msg=='AppLifecycleState.paused' ){
  if(globals.globalCameraOpenedStatus==false)
  locationThreadUpdatedLocation=false;
}

  });
}
```

My global function redirects users to offline home/home page depending on availability of internet when app is resumed currently. I want it to refresh the currently active screen.

Comment: can you share your global function.

Comment: what is the event you want to refresh the page or is it periodical?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

just Simple use

```
setState(() {});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In the future, consider adding some additional detail, such as where this should be added in the user's code and why it will solve the problem.

Comment: Can I use a notification statement like'Refreshing' with set state?

Comment: This wont restart app. This will just rebuild the widget tree. It wont call other components, example initState of your stateful widget

Comment: What if I only use stateless widgets? I use them because I use provider library to preserve state, so I have no reason to use stateful widgets

Comment: Stateless widgets cannot refresh the screen

Answer (score 36):

I once used this workaround for a floatingActionButton that reloaded the active page;

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => super.widget));
```

Comment: he meant `this` instead of `super.widget`

Answer (score 16):

try `(context as Element).reassemble();`

reassemble is the function that is used for hot reload

also i think it's better to say your goal and look at other solutions to fix your problem because I don't think this method is reliable.

**EDIT:** there are some useful tips in the comments.

Comment: sorry didn't worked. It throws an exception Failed assertion: line 2527 pos 14: 'root._parent == null': is not true.

Comment: @Shashank i updated the post, please use `(context as Element).reassemble();` to check if it works

Comment: It is not throwing exception now but the initstate of the page is not called as it is called when the page is pushed to navigator. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: did you read `Element.reassemble` official javadocs? *"This function will only be called during development. In release builds, the ext.flutter.reassemble hook is not available, and so this code will never execute."*

Comment: i've been doing things wrong in flutter all this time. :D

Comment: @pskink i've read that but it's not Element.reassemble it is state.reassemble that doesn't work. but yeah i am not sure if it can be reliable, another solution i can think of is use of `markNeedsBuild()` and `scheduleBuildFor`

Comment: @Shashank initState is only called once but i think you can check if elemnt is StatefulElement and recall the initState().

Comment: @ctrleffive i think your method is more reliable

Answer (score 11):

The same question haunted me for a long time, but in the end I came up with a quite simple answer that works

```
              Navigator.pop(context);  // pop current page
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, "Setting"); // push it back in
```

Answer (score 4):

Use
setState(({})) ;
in the part of your code where you're accessing the values from an api

like this

```
if (data["status"]==200){

    setState(() {
      message= data["message"];
      time = data["message"];
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I've faced these situations. Instead of passing context, what I did was wrapping the page in a [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) with the `null` type, and whenever I need to refresh the page I add a `null` value to sink so the Builder will get updated.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: using `StreamBuilder` that way is a workaround, what you need instead is `StatefulBuilder` or `AnimatedBuilder`, or similar general purpose builders

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at Provider.

You essentially let's you notify state change from one part of your app to another and then have the target widget redraw.

In particular look at ChangeNotifierProvider

Provider is designed to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Only

```dart
setState(() {});
```

or If you're using any state management will change the screen state automatically then new data will be loaded (screen state will be updated)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a calling function for initializing that screen, You just need to recall it again. This example is really useful for upcoming visitors that are using this package: https://pub.dev/packages/stacked

Example:

This is my screen

```
class MyPropertyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyPropertyScreenState createState() => _MyPropertyScreenState();
}

class _MyPropertyScreenState extends State<MyPropertyScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return ViewModelBuilder<MyPropertyViewModel>.reactive(
          viewModelBuilder: () => MyPropertyViewModel(),
          onModelReady: (model) => model.initialized(), //Initalized Function
          builder: (context, model, child) =>
           Scaffold(
        body: ListUI(
    recallModel: model
        )
            ));
    }
}
    
    class ListUI extends StatelessWidget {
    MyPropertyViewModel recallModel;
    
    ListUI ({this.recallModel});
    
    
    pressReload(){
     recallModel.initialized(); //Recall the function again
    }
    }
```

If you are using initState() You can find your way around it using this example.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can refresh currently active page in flutter

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Enter active Screen name ), 
    (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `go_router` and `flutter_i18n`. Changing the current language / Locale is an async operation, i.e. returning a `Future`. Therefore the refresh must occur inside a `then()` call. In my constellation, I want to refresh the settings page after changing the language. This looks as follows:

```
FlutterI18n.refresh(context, Locale(value, '')).then((_) {
  // refresh by replacing the current route by itself - go_router style
  context.pushReplacement('/settings');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

@smebes
works only on debug not on on release --> Description of reassemble()

```
    setState(() {fetchNegotiations();(context as Element).reassemble();}
```

Answer (score -3):

check code

```
 return RefreshIndicator(
                child: CustomScrollView(
                  controller: _scrollController,
                  slivers: <Widget>[
                    SliverAppBar(
                      primary: false,
                      expandedHeight: 75,
                      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFf4eedd),
                      floating: true,
                      actions: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: AssetImage('images/banner.png'),
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill)),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    contentView,
                  ],
                ),
                onRefresh: () async {
                  this._pageLoadController.reset();
                  await Future.value({});
                },
              );
```

Comment: Did you get what I asked?

Comment: @Shashank please explain more