# Flutter Refresh the page after uploading data

Tags: flutter

I am uploading data to the back-end and after successful uploading of data I want refresh the page or you can say reload the page. Is it possible in Flutter?

Comment: You can reload the page using setState(() {}); in Flutter.

Comment: Just by calling set state my screen will be reloaded are uh sure

Comment: you might be calling a api when you load the page so when upload completes use setState or whatever other state management you are using make loading true(so it will show the loader) and call that api again to load the page

Answer (score 0):

If you get a callback from your backend and you want to update the components in your screen you can use SetState. Like this:

> setState(() {
> myComponent.text = myNewValue;   });

there are different solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57985618/how-to-refresh-currently-active-page-in-flutter) depending on what you need.