# Reload WebView every time when hitting buttons at bottom navbar in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-webview

I'm building my first web app using Flutter Webview in which I embedded a bottom Navigation bar that further has 4 Icons.

[image: here]

Each Icon has its Own Class and by pressing on it launches a different Webview for each tab like the below example:

[image: here]

But the problem that I am facing right above is that you can see each tab cannot be pressed more than once at a time. What I'm looking for is to reopen the same tab like a hyperlink in html instead of once only.

[image: here]

Also, I have no idea how to refresh webview page when hitting the refresh icon no matter what page or tab I'm

**main.dart**

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:splash_screen_view/SplashScreenView.dart';
import 'pages/home_page.dart';
import 'pages/profile.dart';
import 'pages/cart.dart';



void main(){
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Color(0xff1e2229)
  ));
   runApp(MyApp());
   
}

 
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     
        Widget spalshfirst = SplashScreenView(
              navigateRoute: WebViewClass(),
              duration: 3000,
              imageSize: 80,
              imageSrc: 'assets/splash.png',
              text: "Food Delivery",
              textType: TextType.TyperAnimatedText,
              textStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 25.0,
              ),
              colors: const [
                Colors.purple,
                Colors.blue,
                Colors.yellow,
                Colors.red,
              ],
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            );

    return  MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            home:  Scaffold(
                       body: spalshfirst 
                      )
              );
  
  }
}
 
class WebViewClass extends StatefulWidget {
  WebViewState createState() => WebViewState();
}

class WebViewState extends State<WebViewClass> with TickerProviderStateMixin{
 
  @override
   void initState() {
     super.initState();
         // Enable hybrid composition.
    if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
   }


 int currentIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

//Including Dart Webview pages
     final screens = [
        HomeClass(),
        Center(child: Text('refresh')),
        ProfileClass(),
        CartClass()
     ];


    return  Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
          appBar: null,
          body: SafeArea(
            child: screens[currentIndex]
          ),
         bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            currentIndex: currentIndex,
            selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
            unselectedItemColor: Colors.white60,
            onTap: (index) => setState(() => currentIndex = index),
            items: const [
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.home),
                  label: 'Home',
                  backgroundColor: Colors.pink       
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.refresh),
                  label: 'Refresh',
                  backgroundColor: Colors.pink
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.profile_circled),
                  label: 'Profile',
                  backgroundColor: Colors.pink
                ),
                 BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.cart),
                  label: 'Cart',
                  backgroundColor: Colors.pink
                )
            ],

        ) ,
    );
  }

}
```

**Webview HomeClass() refrence**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';


class HomeClass extends StatefulWidget {
  Homestate createState() => Homestate();
}

class Homestate extends State<HomeClass> with TickerProviderStateMixin{
  late WebViewController _controller;
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controllerCompleter =  Completer<WebViewController>();
  //Make sure this function return Future<bool> otherwise you will get an error
  Future<bool> _onWillPop(BuildContext context) async {
    if (await _controller.canGoBack()) {
      _controller.goBack();
      return Future.value(false);
    } else {
      return Future.value(true);
    }
  }

 bool isLoading = false;
 final key = UniqueKey();
 int position = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => _goBack(context),
      child: Scaffold(
              appBar: null,
              body: IndexedStack(
                    index: position,
                    children: [
                                WebView(
                                  initialUrl: 'https://google.com',
                                  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                                  key: key,
                                  onPageStarted: (value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      position = 1;
                                    });
                                  },
                                  onPageFinished: (value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      position = 0;
                                    });
                                  },
                                  onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                                    _controllerCompleter.future.then((value) => _controller = value);
                                    _controllerCompleter.complete(webViewController);
                                  },
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: SpinKitDualRing(
                                      color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                                      size: 45.0,
                                      controller: AnimationController(
                                        vsync: this,
                                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1200),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ))
        
      );
  }
//Go back coding
Future<bool> _goBack(BuildContext context) async {
    if (await _controller.canGoBack()) {
      _controller.goBack();
      return Future.value(false);
    } else {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                title: const Text('Do you want to exit from Foodrive?'),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                    child: const Text('No'),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      SystemNavigator.pop();
                    },
                    child: const Text('Yes'),
                  ),
                ],
              ));
      return Future.value(true);
    }

  } 

}
```

Comment: you may refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57985618/how-to-refresh-currently-active-page-in-flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution after paid someone for this answer. In this solution developer added 2 new packages  `import 'package:get/get.dart';` and  `import 'package:testing/pages/navigation_controller.dart';`

**dependencies**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  webview_flutter: ^2.3.0
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
  splash_screen_view: ^3.0.0
  flutter_icons: ^1.1.0
  pull_to_refresh: ^2.0.0 
  get:

 # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.4
```

**main.dart**

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors
// ignore: use_key_in_widget_constructors
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:testing/pages/navigation_controller.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:splash_screen_view/SplashScreenView.dart';
import 'initial_bindings.dart';
import 'pages/home_page.dart';
import 'pages/profile.dart';
import 'pages/cart.dart';

void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Color(0xff1e2229)));

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget spalshfirst = SplashScreenView(
      navigateRoute: WebViewClass(),
      duration: 3000,
      imageSize: 80,
      imageSrc: 'assets/splash.png',
      text: "Food Delivery",
      textType: TextType.TyperAnimatedText,
      textStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 25.0,
      ),
      colors: const [
        Colors.purple,
        Colors.blue,
        Colors.yellow,
        Colors.red,
      ],
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    );
    return GetMaterialApp(
        initialBinding: InitialBindings(),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(body: spalshfirst));
  }
}

class WebViewClass extends StatefulWidget {
  WebViewState createState() => WebViewState();
}

class WebViewState extends State<WebViewClass> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Enable hybrid composition.
    if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
  }

  int currentIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//Including Dart Webview pages
    final screens = [
      HomeClass(),
      // Center(child: Text('refresh')),
      ProfileClass(),
      CartClass()
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      appBar: null,
      body: SafeArea(child: screens[currentIndex]),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.white60,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() => currentIndex = index);
          Get.find<NavigationController>().controller.value?.reload();
        },
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.home),
              label: 'Home',
              backgroundColor: Colors.pink),
          // BottomNavigationBarItem(
          //     icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.refresh),
          //     label: 'Refresh',
          //     backgroundColor: Colors.pink),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.profile_circled),
              label: 'Profile',
              backgroundColor: Colors.red),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.cart),
              label: 'Cart',
              backgroundColor: Colors.pink)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**initial_bindings.dart**

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class NavigationController extends GetxController {
  Rx<WebViewController?> controller = null.obs;
}
```

**Home_page.dart** same code for(profile.dart and cart.dart)

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:pull_to_refresh/pull_to_refresh.dart';
import 'package:testing/pages/navigation_controller.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class HomeClass extends StatefulWidget {
  Homestate createState() => Homestate();
}

class Homestate extends State<HomeClass> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late WebViewController _controller;
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controllerCompleter =
      Completer<WebViewController>();

  final RefreshController _refreshController =
      RefreshController(initialRefresh: false);

  late AnimationController animController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1200),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  //Make sure this function return Future<bool> otherwise you will get an error
  Future<bool> _onWillPop(BuildContext context) async {
    if (await _controller.canGoBack()) {
      _controller.goBack();
      return Future.value(false);
    } else {
      return Future.value(true);
    }
  }

  bool isLoading = false;
  final key = UniqueKey();
  int position = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => _goBack(context),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: null,
        body: SmartRefresher(
          controller: _refreshController,
          enablePullDown: true,
          onRefresh: () {
            Get.find<NavigationController>().controller.value?.reload();
            _refreshController.refreshCompleted();
          },
          child: IndexedStack(
            index: position,
            children: [
              WebView(
                initialUrl: 'https://canada.ca',
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                key: key,
                onPageStarted: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    position = 1;
                  });
                },
                onPageFinished: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    position = 0;
                  });
                },
                onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                  _controllerCompleter.future
                      .then((value) => _controller = value);
                  _controllerCompleter.complete(webViewController);
                  Get.find<NavigationController>().controller =
                      webViewController.obs;
                },
              ),
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                child: Center(
                  child: SpinKitDualRing(
                    color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                    size: 45.0,
                    controller: animController,
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

//Go back coding
  Future<bool> _goBack(BuildContext context) async {
    if (await _controller.canGoBack()) {
      _controller.goBack();
      return Future.value(false);
    } else {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                title: const Text('Do you want to exit from Foodrive?'),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                    child: const Text('No'),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      SystemNavigator.pop();
                    },
                    child: const Text('Yes'),
                  ),
                ],
              ));
      return Future.value(true);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternate approach for this use **ValueNotifier/ValueListenable** in **Tabbar** Widget and listen that object in you **WebView**. When you **onTap** or **onItemSelected** method called just update the value it will called listener in your **child/WebView**. and then you can reload the **WebView**.

HomeTabbar.dart

```
class HomeTabbar extends StatefulWidget {
const HomeTabbar({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeTabbar> createState() => _HomeTabbarState();
}
class _HomeTabbarState extends State<HomeTabbar> {
late PersistentTabController _controller;
final reloadWebView = ValueNotifier(false);

@override
void initState() {
 super.initState();
  _controller = PersistentTabController();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Material(
   elevation: 2,
   child: Scaffold(
     backgroundColor: AppColors.backgroundColor,


    body: Directionality(
          textDirection:
              AppModel.instance.isRTL() ? TextDirection.rtl : TextDirection.ltr,
          child: PersistentTabView(
            context,
            controller: _controller,
            screens: _buildScreens(),
            items: _navBarsItems(),
            confineInSafeArea: true,
            backgroundColor:
                AppColors.backgroundColor, // Default is Colors.white.
            handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true, // Default is true.
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset:
                true, // This needs to be true if you want to move up the screen when keyboard appears. Default is true.
            stateManagement: true, // Default is true.
            hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows:
                true, // Recommended to set 'resizeToAvoidBottomInset' as true while using this argument. Default is true.
            decoration: const NavBarDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
              ),
              colorBehindNavBar: Colors.white,
            ),
            popAllScreensOnTapOfSelectedTab: true,
            popActionScreens: PopActionScreensType.all,
            itemAnimationProperties: const ItemAnimationProperties(
              // Navigation Bar's items animation properties.
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
              curve: Curves.easeOut,
            ),
            screenTransitionAnimation: const ScreenTransitionAnimation(
              // Screen transition animation on change of selected tab.
              animateTabTransition: true,
              curve: Curves.easeOut,
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
            ),
            navBarStyle: NavBarStyle
                .simple, // Choose the nav bar style with this property.
            onItemSelected: (value) {
              if (value == 0) {
                setState(() {
                  reloadWebView.value = !(reloadWebView.value);
                });
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _buildScreens() {
    return [
      GenericWebView(
        url: 'http://google.com',
        reloadWebView: reloadWebView,
      ),
      const SampleView2(),
      const SampleView3(),
    ];
  }

  List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> _navBarsItems() {
    return [
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Transform.scale(
          scale: 3,
          child: const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.abc,
              size: 30.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        title: ("Sample 1"),
        activeColorPrimary: AppColors.whiteColor,
        inactiveColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Transform.scale(
          scale: 3,
          child: const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0),
            child: ImageIcon(
              Icons.abc,
              size: 30.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        title: ("Sample 2"),
        activeColorPrimary: AppColors.whiteColor,
        inactiveColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Transform.scale(
          scale: 3,
          child: const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.abc,
              size: 30.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        title: ("Sample 3"),
        activeColorPrimary: AppColors.whiteColor,
        inactiveColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    reloadWebView.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

WebView.dart

```
class GenericWebView extends StatefulWidget {
GenericWebView({
    super.key,
    required this.url,
    this.hideAppbar = false,
    this.showToolBar = false,
    this.enableLocale = true,
    this.reloadWebView,
  });

  final String url;

  final ValueListenable<bool>? reloadWebView;

  @override
  State<GenericWebView> createState() => _GenericWebViewState();

  String get loadingUrl {
    return '$url';
  }
}

class _GenericWebViewState extends State<GenericWebView> {
  late final WebViewController _controller;
  late bool isLoading = true;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    webViewSetting();
  }

  void webViewSetting() {
    late final PlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams params;
    if (WebViewPlatform.instance is WebKitWebViewPlatform) {
      params = WebKitWebViewControllerCreationParams(
        allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
        mediaTypesRequiringUserAction: const <PlaybackMediaTypes>{},
      );
    } else {
      params = const PlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams();
    }

    final WebViewController controller =
        WebViewController.fromPlatformCreationParams(params);

    controller
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onProgress: (int progress) {
            debugPrint('WebView is loading (progress : $progress%)');
          },
          onPageStarted: (String url) {
            isLoading = true;
            currentUrl = url;
            debugPrint('Page started loading: $url');
          },
          onPageFinished: (String url) {
            isLoading = false;
            setState(() {});
            currentUrl = url;
            debugPrint('Page finished loading: $url');
          },
          onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {
             ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                 snackBarWhenFailure(snackBarFailureText: error.description));
             isLoading = false;
             setState(() {});
             debugPrint('''
 Page resource error:
   code: ${error.errorCode}
   description: ${error.description}
   errorType: ${error.errorType}
   isForMainFrame: ${error.isForMainFrame}
          ''');
          },
          onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
            // if (request.url.startsWith(widget.url)) {
            //   debugPrint('blocking navigation to ${request.url}');
            //   return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            // }
            debugPrint('allowing navigation to ${request.url}');
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
          onUrlChange: (UrlChange change) {
            debugPrint('url change to ${change.url}');
          },
        ),
      )
      ..addJavaScriptChannel(
        'Toaster',
        onMessageReceived: (JavaScriptMessage message) {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(content: Text(message.message)),
          );
        },
      )
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(widget.loadingUrl));

    // #docregion platform_features
    if (controller.platform is AndroidWebViewController) {
      AndroidWebViewController.enableDebugging(true);
      (controller.platform as AndroidWebViewController)
          .setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    }
    // #enddocregion platform_features

    _controller = controller;
    widget.reloadWebView?.addListener(() {
      if (currentUrl != widget.loadingUrl) {
        setState(() {
          isLoading = true;
          _controller.loadRequest(Uri.parse(widget.loadingUrl));
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: AppColors.backgroundColor,
      appBar: widget.hideAppbar
          ? null
          : BaseAppBar(
              appBar: AppBar(),
              key: const Key('Web_App_bar'),
            ),
      body: Directionality(
        textDirection:
            AppModel.instance.isRTL() ? TextDirection.rtl : TextDirection.ltr,
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              WebViewWidget(
                controller: _controller,
                layoutDirection: AppModel.instance.isRTL()
                    ? TextDirection.rtl
                    : TextDirection.ltr,
              ),
              isLoading
                  ? const Center(child: CustomProgressIndicator())
                  : Stack(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```